# Как отследить, нажал юзер на ссылку или нет?

Tags: yii2, ссылки

Передо мной стоит задача: Отправить письмо на почту админа, при скачивании файла с сайта. Я не могу придумать как это сделать. Я не знаю как отследить, нажал юзер на ссылку или нет. И если даже как-то отслежу, то ее мне нужно куда-то и как-то записывать, что бы передать в скрипт отправки сообщений. Подскажи как мне сделать?
Это нужно реализовать на Yii2.
За ранее большое спасибо))

Answer (score 0):

Нужно перехватывать нажатия по ссылке и перед тем, как это нажатие будет обработано классическим путем, отправить синхронный ajax запрос.

```js
$(function(){
  $('a.catch').click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
      async: false,
      //......
      success: function(data){
        return true;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="catch" href="http://ya.ru/">ССЫЛКА</a>
```